# Increase of virtualbox disk size

Tags: virtualbox, linux-mint

I need to increase my disk space in my guest Mint Linux, on a Mac OS host.

First I increased the virtual disk in the host with:

```
VboxManage modifyhd Mint.vdi --resize 20480
```

The GUI of VirtualBox Manager confirms: "IDE Primary Master: Mint.vdi (Normal, 20.00 GB)"

However in the guest, `sudo fdisk -l` gives:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
```

Notes that this is not the partition (not `sda1`, but `sda`).

I have read a number of guides for this, but in all of them `/dev/sda` increased automatically in the guest. How to make sure that the guest OS sees the whole device?

GParted Live does not see the extra space either.

Comment: Is your VM snapshotted? If using a snapshot, you're VM is only using that .vdi file as a base, and is using a "differencing disk" for the difference between the original .vdi and the snapshot.

Comment: You are likely to be correct, but I cannot remove the snapshot. When I try to delete it (and merge to the vdi) I only get an error message "VERR_INVALID_PARAMETER", Component Medium, "VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004)". The "Details" tab gives now "Mind.vdi (Normal, Inaccessible)", but the VM does start normally.

Comment: This might in turn be because I changed the disk size while snapshotted, but I cannot reduce it anymore with `modifyhd`. I get "VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still do not know why GParted could not see the whole device. As snapshoe suggested it might because the VM had snapshots.

Trying to remove snapshots *after* running `modifyhd` did not succeed.

Here is how it was solved:

I had to create a new virtual disk from within VirtualBox, then clone the old one to the new one:

```
VBoxManage clonehd Mint.vdi NewMind.vdi --existing
```

Then I had to disconnect the old disk from the VM, and run GParted to expend the existing guest partition to the whole of the device.