# How to increase Virtualbox disk size?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

I am using Windows XP under VirtualBox and using a hard disk from a `.hdd` format file.
My problem is, even after trying hard, I can't resize my hard disk.

Can anyone help me to resize my VirtualBox hard disk in `.hdd` (not `.vdi`) format? Or converting `.hdd` to `.vdi` format?

My primary OS is Ubuntu 12.04.

PS: `VboxManage modifyhd XXX.vdi --resize YYYY` does not work for `.hdd` format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increase of virtualbox disk size](http://superuser.com/questions/589257/increase-of-virtualbox-disk-size)

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy~ You missed the main point. that is the answer for increasing the hard-disk for VboxManage modifyhd Mint **.vdi** --resize 20480. My requirement is for **.hdd** format the one used in Mac.

Answer (score 2):

Found the following solution:

`.hdd` cannot be managed by any of VirtualBox Tools since the documentations for `.hhd` format are not maintained within VirtualBox (but with Parallels, so easy to work with `.HDD` format in Mac OS X).

- Go to *File*, select *VirtualBox Manager*.
- Select the `.hdd` disk and select *Clone*
- In the destination format choose `.vdi` and perform cloning.
- Use `VboxManage modifyhd XXX.vdi --resize YYYY` from terminal to increase the disk size.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any utilities within virtualbox to resize a .HDD file.  I would create a new .HDD file and use dd to clone the drive to a larger one.  Then delete the old.  This is also a great way to move a physical HDD to a virtual HDD.

This method is slow but very effective.

Comment: Do you know how to convert .hdd to .vdi format?