# How can I increase the size of a lubuntu virtual machine in VirtualBox?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, disk-space

I am using VirtualBox 6 on Windows 10. I have used the Virtual Media Manager to increase the size of my lubuntu virtual machine. However, I cannot access that additional space within the virtual machine.

I have also tried `VBoxManage modifymedium disk "C:\Users\myusername\VirtualBox VMs\lubuntu\lubuntu.vdi" --resize 32768` in the command prompt, but this did not fix it.

When I issue `sudo fdisk -l` I get (among many `Disk /dev/loop` entries):

```
Disk /dev/sda: 16 GiB, 17179869184 bytes, 33554432 sectors
Disk model: VBOX HARDDISK   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x56d7e4ab

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        2048 33543719 33541672  16G 83 Linux
```

so it seems that the new space has been created as `/dev/sda1`, but has not been merged with the main partition `/dev/sda`.

Comment: When you issued the command what was the output?  I assume the current disk is larger than 32768?  FYI: `VboxManage` does not support shrinking disks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase of virtualbox disk size](https://superuser.com/questions/589257/increase-of-virtualbox-disk-size)

Comment: @Ramhound `0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%`

Comment: That means the virtual HDD was expanded.  This only effected the file on the host itself.  You have to also expand the drive within the guest OS.  Instead of replying with a comment you should [edit] your question.  The duplicate to this question explains the entire process and answers your question.

Comment: @Ramhound I have tried to follow the instructions in the other post. However, I am stuck on the final steps. It says to "disconnect the old disk from the VM". I am not really sure how to do this and it doesn't provide instructions. Can you help?

Comment: I will be unable to do that since this is a duplicate and I don’t answer questions that are duplicates.  It’s also unclear what you are stuck on

Comment: @Ramhound If you look at https://superuser.com/questions/589257/increase-of-virtualbox-disk-size, and go to the accepted answer, and read the last sentence, there are details there which I do not understand how to carry out: "Then I had to disconnect the old disk from the VM, and run GParted to expend the existing guest partition to the whole of the device." Perhaps you could improve that accepted answer. How do I disconnect the old disk from the VM?

Comment: How you expand a disk in Linux within a VM is well documented.  You have already increased the virtual HDD all you have to do is increase the size within the guest os

Comment: @Ramhound can you link me please? I have tried many things but all have failed.